# Is Pascal's law incorrect?

Tags: pressure, surface-tension, fluid-statics, capillary-action

Consider the figure given below.
[image]

Here I'm gonna talk about capillarity. The liquid inside the beaker as well as the column is water. As water has a tendency to rise in the capillary as shown, doesn't it violate Pascal's law.

At equilibrium when water has risen in the tube, pressure at point A as well as the pressure at water surface which is open to atmosphere will be $1$ $atm$. In turn pressure at point B will be $1$ $atm$ as it is at the same level above the ground as water in beaker ( Pascal's law ). Which means that $P_a-P_b$ is zero but according to Pascal's law it should have been $h\rho g$.

What's wrong then.

Comment: Pressure at Point A(just inside liquid) is less than a point just above it.
The discontinuity is due to the phenomenon of surface tension due to which the pressure across the meniscus is different.(Pressure suffers discontinuity at the meniscus)

Comment: Again, asking "Is this well-established law incorrect?" appeals to me as a drastically bad question. It's much more reasonable to ask _how_ a certain law can be applied to the given situation. Can you edit the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the pressure at B is (approximately) equal to atmospheric pressure, so Pascal's law holds. The pressure in the tube above B is lower than atmospheric ($p_a=p_b-\rho gh$). The difference in pressure between the liquid and the atmosphere at A is compensated by the force of surface tension at the meniscus.

When you insert a thin tube into a beaker of water, the water will rise up the tube until the weight of water above the point B equals the force exerted by the meniscus. This is why the water rises higher in a thinner tube, because a greater height is required to achieve the same balancing volume/weight. You can find more details on the Wikipedia page for [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action).

Comment: Going a bit beyond this, it is perfectly possible for the pressure to be negative, giving a liquid under tension - and this [goes on regularly in trees if they are tall enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BickMFHAZR0).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I assume you mean negative gauge pressure, not absolute? Surely below the vapor pressure, the water would vaporize/flash?

Comment: See the video. I mean absolute pressure.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty wow. Mind --> blown. Great video, that's really fascinating! Thanks :-)